# Get first element from a Set, if it exists, in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I'm using the [containers](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.7.1/docs/Data-Set.html) library and I'm trying to extract the first element out of a set using this approach in the REPL:

```
let initialSet = insert "x" empty
let setWithTwoElems = insert "y" initialSet
elemAt 0 (filter (\v -> v == "x") setWithTwoElems)
```

While this works it's not safe if the predicate passed to filter doesn't match any of the elements in the Set. If I do for example:

```
elemAt 0 (filter (\v -> v == "z") setWithTwoElems)
```

it'll blow up saying:

```
"*** Exception: Set.elemAt: index out of range
CallStack (from HasCallStack):
  error, called at libraries/containers/Data/Set/Base.hs:1186:16 in containers-0.5.7.1:Data.Set.Base
```

which kind of defies the purpose of using Haskell? I'd like something similar to `elemAt` (or just `first`) that returns a `Maybe` result instead.

How can I do this?

Comment: What are you really trying to do? You're putting `"x"` and `"y"` into a `Set`, then filtering on e.g. `"x"`. If it's there, the return value will *also* be `"x"`. Basically, then, can't you use `member` to query whether or not `"x"` is in the `Set`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The function you are looking for is called `find` and comes from `Data.Foldable`.

From the [documentation](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/Data-Foldable.html#v:find):

> The find function takes a predicate and a structure and returns the leftmost element of the structure matching the predicate, or Nothing if there is no such element.

Therefore, you can use `find (\v -> v == "x") setWithTwoElems`

Comment: or `find (== "x") setWithTwoElems` ;)

Comment: ...but if you are using it with `(==)` predicates, you *probably* just want `member :: Ord a => a -> Set a -> Bool`, which will need only O(log n) comparisons instead of O(n) equality checks. (Yes, I know it is possible to construct pathological examples where this is not the right function, but we are certainly not in those cases if we're dealing with `Set String`s.)